Mono repo add cli binary of local package to node_modules after building/transpiling
In our mono repo we have a package with a CLI written in Typescript and gets built/transpiled for production packaging. As the package.json bin targets the dist folder, which gets created after transpiling/building, yarn install does not create a symlink for the binary in node_modules/.bin. Also in order to transpile/build in the first place, node_modules have to be installed, so yarn install has to be ran before.
Is there a workaround to add the binary to my local node_modules after transpiling/building, e.g. creating the symlink manually with a postbuild script?
